# Display Typescript class hierarchy in VS Code

Tags: typescript, class, visual-studio-code, hierarchy

is there any way (native or extension) in VS Code to see class inheritance hierarchy of some class in Typescript?

Something like Type Hierarchy view for Java classes in Eclipse?

[image: Type Hierarchy in Eclipse]

Thanx

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about Visual Studio extension, but if UML diagram is also an option, you can try

**[TypeScript UML Playground](https://tsuml-demo.firebaseapp.com/)**

Sample result of Raytracer program
[image]

Comment: Thanx, looks interesting. It will be useful as VS Code extension, but considering "Work in progress" comment and having last change 2 years ago, this is probably dead path.